# Change storyboard "View As" device in code

Tags: swift, xcode

I am developing a card game iPhone app using one storyboard for all iPhone sizes.  There is some minor animation in the app.  The app runs fine and works well in each simulation as long as the “View As” device I choose in the main storyboard matches the simulator I am running.  If I choose a different simulator, not matching the “View As” device in the main storyboard then the animations do not work correctly.  Is there anyway to set the “View As” storyboard device in code, so it will be set correctly depending on the type of iPhone running the app?

Answer (score 0):

Auto Layout is the answer for your question. You have to setup constraints for all your views and then it will correctly resize depending on the current device.

Go to the official [Apple Auto Layout guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/) for more information